# Configure samba server for Unix group

Tags: active-directory, redhat, authentication, samba

I'm trying to set up a samba server with access for users in the Linux (RHEL 6) "wheel" group. I am basing smb.conf off of the example [here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html) where it goes through the `[accounting]` example. In my `smb.conf` I have

```
[tmp]
    comment = temporary files
    path = /var/share
    valid users = @wheel
    read only = No
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 02777
    max connections = 0
```

(rest of the output from `$ testparm /etc/samba/smb.conf` is [here](https://gist.github.com/d10genes/7144283)). And

```
groups `whoami`
```

returns `user01 : wheel`.

When I use the following command from another machine (Mac OS) as the Linux user (`user01`):

```
$ smbclient -L NETBIOSNAME/tmp
```

it asks for a password, I hit return without a password, and get:

```
Enter user01's password:
Anonymous login successful
Domain=[DOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.9-151.el6_4.1]
Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    tmp             Disk      temporary files
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server Version 3.6.9-151.el6_4.1)
```

But when I try

```
$ smbclient //NETBIOSNAME/tmp
```

I try typing the password I use for the Linux login, and get a bunch of stuff logged, including

```
check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'user01' in passdb.
...
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

(I can give more logging information if it would be helpful.)

I can't find a reference to more steps I need to add group users in the resource. Should I be manually adding samba users from the group somehow?

Comment: What kind of account storage backend are you using? Samba does not directly read /etc/passwd but, rather, will use a backend such as "tdbsam" or "ldapsam" as documented [here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/passdb.html). So you would need to create "user01" in the  user storage backend used by Samba.

Comment: I have `passdb backend = tdbsam` in the global settings. Looks like using unix groups will be less straightforward than I thought... Thanks for the reference.

Comment: From what I understand you have to create 1) create the system "user01" 2) Create the Samba "user01" in tdbsam with "smbpasswd -a user01" 3) Add "user01" to the system group wheel and then it may work.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping setting 'valid users = @wheel' would extract the existing wheel group members, but appears it's more complicated than that. I was able to get one user working with `smbpasswd -a user01`, and there's only a handful of users anyways, so doing it one-by-one shouldn't be too hard. I'll just have to look into options to sync unix passwords now since it doesn't sync automatically.

Comment: You can use "ldapsam" as a central source for Unix and Samba to avoid having to sync up users. I will post an answer for the immediate problem shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here was that the Samba user storage did not have the system user present. The solution, in this case was

1. Create system user "user01" (already done)
2. Create samba user with `smbpasswd -a user01`
3. Add "user01" to the system wheel group

then the user is able to access the share. To avoid maintenance of two user databases you could consider something like LDAP.